# im trying to make a gradient unity gui in C# and I got this

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Gradient g = new Gradient();
GradientColorKey[] gck = new GradientColorKey[2];
GradientAlphaKey[] gak = new GradientAlphaKey[2];
gck[0].color = new Color(75f,0f,130f);
gck[0].time = 1.0F;
gck[1].color = Color.blue;
gck[1].time = -1.0F;
gak[0].alpha = 0.0F;
gak[0].time = 1.0F;
gak[1].alpha = 0.0F;
gak[1].time = -1.0F;
gck[2].color = Color.cyan;
gck[2].time = 1.0F;
gak[2].alpha = 0.0F;
gak[2].time = 1.0F;
g.SetKeys(gck, gak);
gameObject.AddComponent<Renderer>().material.color = g.Evaluate(1);
---->   this.guiColor = new Color(gck[0].color, gck[1].color, gck[2].color);
this.colorTimer += Time.deltaTime;
```

The error:

> Cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Color' to 'float' for all 3 arguments

I tried making it a float but that caused in error in itself

Comment: Do you understand the error message?

Comment: This question literally has nothing to do with `[csharpcodeprovider]` (tag description: .NET class that provides access to the C# compiler for compiling code.) or with `[dnspy]` (tag description: A debugger and .NET assembly editor. It can be used to edit and debug assemblies even if no source code available is available.). Apparently you're using Unity, so I wonder why you opted to add two completely unrelated tags, but not add a Unity tag.

Comment: Apparently this is the [second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76151675/how-do-you-get-a-gradient-on-a-gui) I have pointed out to you that `[csharpcodeprovider]` is not relevant for your question, and that you should tag Unity. Why do you persist on adding something irrelevant?! If you don't listen to advice about your question, why would we expect you to listen to advice on solving your problem? It seems like an exercise in futility...

Comment: well `new Color` takes as parameters `float red, float green, float blue` (+ opional `float alpha`) ... you are passing in `Color, Color, Color` ... what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: You cant make a colour by putting "Color(gck[0].color, gck[1].color, gck[2].color)"  they need rgb values not white black and blue

Answer (score 0):

As derHugo said, gck and gak are arrays of colors, but when you are assigning `this.guiColor` color, in the three arguments of the constructor, you are passing `gck[0].color, gck[1].color, gck[2].color`, which are colors, not floats, which is what is required. It is unclear what you are trying to do, you can't create a color from three other colors, unless you want the average of them or something, but that's not done like this.

note: on your 4th line you are adding f's at the end of each number to make them floats, but you don't need this unless they are decimals